# Fixar página com Reveal Modal do Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Tenho um modal feito com Foundation, o que pretendo é fixar o fundo da página, e só movimentar o modal, segue um modelo:
[Exemplo de modal com scroll](https://trello.com/c/MOzvXJUq/106-complete-trello-api-v1)

Como posso realizar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Em geral, para colocar scroll usa-se:

```
#elemento{
   overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: Conseguir resolver o problema, deu um position:fixed em uma div!